# How do I store HTML form inputs on a Node JS variable?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I am unable to set the values of HTML form inputs on to my Node JS variable. 
Below is my JS code where I am not able to set the values of variables "hostname" and "port" which will in turn concatenate to a new variable called url.

console.log(url) prints just mongodb://:. which suggests that my HTML form values are not being stored in my Node JS variables.

```
var express     = require('express');        // call express
var app         = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var router      = express.Router();  

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        

var router = express.Router();              

const dbname    = "admin";

var hostname ='';
var port2 ='';

app.post('/', function(req, res){ 
    hostname = req.body.hostname;
    port2 = req.body.port2;
});

var url ="mongodb://"+hostname+":"+port2;
```

Below is my html which is handling the form inputs

```
    <form class="clr-form" action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="hostname" placeholder="Enter Host Name" class="clr-input"> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="port2" placeholder="Enter Port" class="clr-input"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You should move the URL creation inside of the app.post. The .js file will only run once, so your URL will be created at server startup. If you move it into the app.post, it will be created on each post request.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to redeclare the port2 again

```
var port2 ='';

app.post('/', function(req, res){ 
    var hostname = req.body.hostname;
    port2 = req.body.port2;
});

var url ="mongodb://"+hostname+":"+port2;
```

Comment: Hi about that - I was doing trial and error probably forgot to change the code from when I declared the variable inside the function to make it accessible to within the function. The problem is I am unable to get the inputs I entered on my html to my node console

Comment: call this api from your html

Comment: My node app is listening at localhost port 8080. What value should my form action have? "http://localhost:8080/"? Also where should app.post('/') route to?

Comment: Also I think I can achieve the same by making use req.query supported by express. Any idea about this?

Comment: yes you can access them with req.query.property_name

Comment: Here we have two case:
i) app.post("/?key=value'')
  you can access this via req.query.key
ii) app.post("/:key"')
  you can access this via req.params.key

Comment: Sorry if it is too much to ask but can you please give me the html input form as well as the way to store my inputs to node js variable in a more structured way. Having trouble with my api call not sure where I am going wrong since I am very new to Node JS

As of now
form action=""http://localhost:8080/""  and 

app.post('/', function(req, res){ 
    hostname = req.body.hostname;
    port2 = req.body.port2;
});

Comment: create repository share me the link

Comment: Sure will make a git repo in another hour and share the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its my pleasure, Even I have taken help in my learning days.
Its time to payback @UtsavGhosh

Comment: https://github.com/utsavgh/formData here is my git repo and thanks a ton for your valuable time. Want to get this thing done as my college project submission dates are near.  Here is my mail id: uzumakiutsav@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, I will do it and let you know

Comment: Hi, any luck regarding this?

Comment: I have not tried yet, but will try to finish it by weekend

Comment: Did you get time to go through the repo? One thing I found out was my api endpoint was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hostname ='';
var port2 ='';

app.post('/', function(req, res){ 
     hostname = req.body.hostname;
     port2 = req.body.port2;
});
```

You should not declare variables inside the function again if you want to assign body values to your variables which one you will be using outside of scope.

Comment: Hi about that - I was doing trial and error probably forgot to change the code from when I declared the variable inside the function to make it accessible to within the function. The problem is I am unable to get the inputs I entered on my html to my node console